# ngrok: Access subdirectory URLs in Django

Tags: django, ngrok

I am using ngrok to test my website. I am able to launch the home page, but how do I launch directories other than homepage? such as 127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing? I get `Error 500: Internal Server Error`. Any solution?

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> Bette | Apartment Listing</title>
</head>
<body>


<head>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load humanize %}  
{% load leaflet_tags %}
    {% load geojson_tags %}
    {% block extra_assets %}
        {% leaflet_js plugins="forms" %}
        {% leaflet_css plugins="forms" %}
    {% endblock %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load social_share %}

{% post_to_facebook http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing "Post to Facebook!" %}
{% post_to_gplus http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing "Post to Google+!" %}
{% post_to_linkedin http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing %}
{% post_to_telegram "New Apartment: {{object.title}}" http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/ %}

<style type="text/css">
.input-group{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  height: 4rem;
}
.cards {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

{% block map %}


 <div class="cards">
          <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Apartments Found</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
   Nearby Apartments | በቅርብ ያሉ (በ 2km): ({{apartments|length}}) 
    {% for obj in filter.qs %}
        {{ obj.apt_id }} - በብር {{ obj.apt_cost }} : {{ obj.apt_subcity }} ; D፡ {{obj.distance.m|floatformat:"2"|intcomma:False}} m
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">{% include 'django_filter.html' %}</div>
         <div class="card">
{% leaflet_map "map" callback="ourfunction" %}
      
<script type="text/javascript">

var csrftoken = "{{ csrf_token }}";

      function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      }

      $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
      });

    
var collection = {{ object_list|geojsonfeature:"popupContent"|safe }};
  console.log(collection);


var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("myModal"));
myModal.show();

  

function ourfunction(map, options) {
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 14});

map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);


    function onLocationFound(e) {


    var radius = e.accuracy;
    var position= e.latlng;
    var counter = 0;
    
    postdate = new Date(); 
    var datetime = postdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (postdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + postdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + postdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + postdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + postdate.getSeconds();
    var lat= e.latlng.lat;
    var lng= e.latlng.lng;
    
    map.panTo(position,16);
    var user_loc ="Point ("+ lat+" "+lng+")";
    console.log(user_loc);
    console.log(postdate);
    
         
    var form = $('<form action="{% url "rent_app:apartment-listing" %}" method="POST">{{ form.as_p }}{% csrf_token %} </form>');

    $('body').append(form);

   

   

    L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map).bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point",{autoClose:false}).openPopup();


function onEachFeature(feature, layer) { 

    // does this feature have a property named popupContent?
    if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
        
        layer.addTo(map).bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent,{autoClose:false}).openPopup();


};  

}



    
    //unique autoincrement id for each user location

    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

    map.on('locationerror', onLocationError);
        
    L.geoJson(collection, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
    
}

    }  

</script>
  

{% endblock %}
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>


C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\WebMap\rentapartments>py -3.9 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

June 12, 2021 - 18:58:52
Django version 3.2.4, using settings 'rentapartments.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4876
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:22] "GET /static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1918
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:43] "GET /static/leaflet/leaflet.css HTTP/1.1" 200 14471
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:43] "GET /static/leaflet/leaflet.js HTTP/1.1" 200 142673
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:43] "GET /static/leaflet/leaflet.extras.js HTTP/1.1" 200 8468
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:46] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1912
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:47] "GET /static/js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.js HTTP/1.1" 200 7154
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:48] "GET /static/js/jquery.bootstrap.modal.forms.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2608
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:50] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1912
[12/Jun/2021 19:01:52] "GET /static/leaflet/images/reset-view.png HTTP/1.1" 200 159
[12/Jun/2021 19:02:01] "GET /apartment_listing HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /apartment_listing/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 278, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 152, in compile_func
    args, kwargs = parse_bits(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 291, in parse_bits
    args.append(parser.compile_filter(bit))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 563, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 662, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing' from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing'
[12/Jun/2021 19:02:03] "GET /apartment_listing/ HTTP/1.1" 500 181555
[12/Jun/2021 19:02:03,305] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 56090)

[12/Jun/2021 19:07:58] "GET /apartment_listing HTTP/1.1" 301 0
Internal Server Error: /apartment_listing/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 278, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 152, in compile_func
    args, kwargs = parse_bits(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 291, in parse_bits
    args.append(parser.compile_filter(bit))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 563, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 662, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing' from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing'
[12/Jun/2021 19:08:00] "GET /apartment_listing/ HTTP/1.1" 500 180768
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[12/Jun/2021 19:10:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3968
Internal Server Error: /apartment_listing/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 278, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 152, in compile_func
    args, kwargs = parse_bits(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 291, in parse_bits
    args.append(parser.compile_filter(bit))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 563, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 662, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing' from 'http://127.0.0.1:8000\apartment_listing'
[12/Jun/2021 19:15:43] "GET /apartment_listing/ HTTP/1.1" 500 180768
Internal Server Error: /apartment_listing/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py", line 29, in get_template
    return Template(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 278, in do_extends
    nodelist = parser.parse()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 478, in parse
    raise self.error(token, e)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 476, in parse
    compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 152, in compile_func
    args, kwargs = parse_bits(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 291, in parse_bits
    args.append(parser.compile_filter(bit))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 563, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 662, in __init__
    raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' "
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing' from 'http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartm
ent_listing'
[12/Jun/2021 19:16:57] "GET /apartment_listing/ HTTP/1.1" 500 180916
[12/Jun/2021 19:18:11,361] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 11253)

[12/Jun/2021 19:18:11,362] - Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 52355)
```

Comment: Turn DEBUG on and show us the output.

Comment: @Ene P I posted the error log.

Comment: There's something wrong in your templates. Can you post them too?

Comment: @EneP Added Template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap these URLs in quotes and check which is the correct order, URL first or title first, because these are custom tags and I don't know exactly how to use them.

```
{% post_to_facebook http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing "Post to Facebook!" %}
{% post_to_gplus http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing "Post to Google+!" %}
{% post_to_linkedin http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/apartment_listing %}
{% post_to_telegram "New Apartment: {{object.title}}" http://5442111b8deb.ngrok.io/ %}
```